# Problem Getting Text With Selenium (PYTHON)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, speech-to-text

I'm trying to build a speech-to-text for my AI voice assistant using Selenium, and so far everything is going right, besides the fact that I can't get the output text.
Here's the [website I'm using](https://speechnotes.co/dictate/) for speech to text.
Here's my code:

```
from time import sleep
import warnings
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

try:
    path = "c:\\Users\\Utente\\Desktop\\SPARK\\chromedriver.exe"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = False
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    service = Service(path)
    options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://speechnotes.co/dictate/")
        
    sleep(1.5)

    it_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/select/option[42]"
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=it_button_xpath).click()
    sleep(0.1)

    start_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div"
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=start_button_xpath).click()
    print("Listening...")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

while True:
    text_element_xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]"
    text = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=text_element_xpath).text
    text = text.strip()
    stop = input("Type anything to stop --> ")
    print(text)
    if stop != "":
        driver.quit()
        break
```

I'm pretty sure that it's because I'm getting the wrong xpath of the output box element, but I tried all I could think of and it still doesn't work.
Also, if it could be of any help, when I try to print(len(text)) it gives 3, I don't know why.
Please help guys,
Thanks

I tried `start_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div"` as well as `start_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/textarea"` but it didn't work (nothing gets printed).

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a good explanation of the problem.  Please show us what the code **actually does**, and explain what you wanted instead.

Comment: Why not find the start button by its id `"start_button"`?

Comment: @JohnGordon it just won't print anything

Comment: @The_spider i mean ok i could do that but that's not the problem

Comment: What do you mean "it just won't print anything"?  Does it print the `Listening...` message?  Does it show the `Type anything to stop --> ` input prompt?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes it does all that, sorry for being vague, i was sure i attached a screenshot of the terminal. by the way it prints everything it's supposed to print but the output

Comment: So what **specific** message doesn't appear?  The `print(text)` message?

Comment: @JohnGordon exactly

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for the `Type anything to stop --> ` input prompt to appear, but not the `print(text)` output.  If `text` is a blank string, that output would appear as simply a blank line.  Are you **sure** it doesn't even print a blank line?

Comment: To test for this, try changing that print message to `print("Text is:", text)`

Comment: it DOES indeed print a blank line, my bad! it will print Text is: followed by nothing

Comment: Okay, so the element that is found by `text_element_xpath` does not itself have any text.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code.

1. Don't use absolute xpath locators. You have quite unique locators on your elements, ids `start_button` and `copy_button`.
2. After you dictated your text, there is no direct element in DOM which contain it. However, you have `copyButton` that can copy text in clipboard. You just need to get it. For example, using `pyperclip`.

Be aware that there can be Google Ads modal that can intercept the click to the copy button. So if you have it - you need to make it invisible or close it.

```py
import pyperclip
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

# previous code
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'start_button').click()
print("Listening...")

while True:
    stop = input("Type anything to stop --> ")
    if stop != "":
        copy = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'copyButton')
        copy.click()
        copied_text = pyperclip.paste()
        print(copied_text)
        driver.quit()
        break
```

Comment: I have just tried to use the copy button and it all worked fine, but the problem is that everytime it click copy the cursor goes to the beginning of the sentence

Comment: @fanti so, simulate arrow right after click on copy `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'results_box').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)`

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver import Keys`

Comment: yup did that and that worked with pyautogui, thanks!